Using a condition in Alteryx but doing nothing if none of the conditions match then do nothing
I have a survey that as fields like
"4 - agree"
"3 - neutral"
"2 - disagree"
"1 - completely disagree"
and random comments which consists of open-ended feedback.
I want to replace the first 4 with 4, 3, 2, 1 respectively - but if it not any of those then I just want to keep it as it is.
For example, if it just says "The session was good" I'd just like to leave it like that.
I have tried switch, and tried to use two "replace()" and IF statement, but it does not seem to work.

Does something like this work, in a Formula tool:
IF left(trim([field]),1) in ('1','2','3','4') THEN
    left(trim([field]),1)
ELSE
    [field]
ENDIF

